# Array not initializing itself or filling its indexes properly

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

I am working on [this](https://www.codechef.com/problems/MAXDIFF) problem from CodeChef and I am having a small problem with an array that I am initializing with a size that is input by the user, but I am getting returned an array that seems to have initialized itself and I dont know why. I know I can just look up others peoples submissions and 'copy and paste' but I want to know what I am doing wrong and how to fix it so I can implement my own code not someone elses.

Here is what the theory looks like:

```
string _input1 = Console.ReadLine().Replace(" ", "");// Get number of items
int[] _weightsArray = new int[_input1[0]];// Set size to number of items
```

Once the user has entered a number say the numbers 5 and 3, the array is supposed to get the number indexed at 0 (which is 5 and set the array to that index) and then the user enters 5 random digits separated by white space and then those digits are filled into the array.

However in this example the array is not set to an index size of 5, it is set to a size of 53 and when the array is filled with 49 at every index.

Here is the full code:

```
Int16 _testCases = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());// Get test cases

for (int i = 0; i < _testCases; i++) {
      string _input1 = Console.ReadLine().Replace(" ", "");// Get number of items
      string _weights = Console.ReadLine().Replace(" ", "");
      int[] _weightsArray = new int[_input1[0]];// Set size to number of items

      for (int j = 0; j < _weights.Length; j++) {
           _weightsArray[j] = Convert.ToInt32(_weights[j]);// Add weights to array
            }

       for (int k = 0; k < _weightsArray.Length; k++) {
            Console.WriteLine(_weightsArray[k]);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();   
}
```

As you can see _weightsArray is supposed to be set to _input1[0] and through debugging I can confirm that _index1[0] is infact the int input by the user but for some reason the compiler completely ignores this.

Here is the actual output, the array is sized more than 5 and does not contain any of the given digits (2, 2, 2, 2,)

[image]

Why is it giving me random index size and 50 for every index?

Thankyou

Comment: first mistake I see in this loop `for (int k=0;...` you are using `i` as an index instead of `k`

Comment: good eye thanks fixed it up

Comment: same thing really just 50 50 50 50 50 and the rest 0's

Comment: Hint: `_input1` and `weights` are `string`, but should be `string[]`. Change the variable types and use `Split` instead of `Replace`

Comment: Why the close votes? What's wrong with this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `_input1` is a string, so when you create an array with

```
int[] _weightsArray = new int[_input1[0]];
```

you are creating an array whose size is the value of the first char (which is 50 is your string starts with 2).

What you actually want to do is to convert the string to an integer:

```
int _weightsArraySize = Convert.ToInt32(_input1);
int[] _weightsArray = new int[_weightsArraySize];
```

The string with the weights is a bit more complicated to parse. First, we want to separate it on spaces to get an array of strings with the inputs:

```
    string[] _stringWeightsArray = _weights.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Then, we want to convert each string to the corresponding integer:

```
    for (int k = 0; k < _weightsArraySize; k++) {
        _weightsArray[k] = Convert.ToInt32(_stringWeightsArray[k]);
    }
```

At this point, you should at least have correctly parsed the input for your problem.

Be warned, however, that this code is very basic, and everything will just explode if your input is not in the expected format (e.g. if you type a letter in the weights, or something like that).